# mkdir: cannot create directory `/opt/schrodinger2015-3': Permission denied

Tags: software-installation

```
Installation of schrodinger2015 terminated by the denial of permission to make the directory /opt/schrodinger2015-3
mkdir: cannot create directory `/opt/schrodinger2015-3': Permission denied.
```

I am new in the area of linux. How can I get over this?

Comment: Were you running installation as root ? for instance , `sudo ./installer.run`

Answer (score 4):

In the [installation guide](http://www.schrodinger.com/Download.php?type=supportdocs&ident=1044), you can read

```
tar -xvf Schrodinger_Internet_Download.tar
cd Schrodinger_Internet_Download
```

But instead of

```
sh ./INSTALL
```

run

```
sudo sh ./INSTALL
```

---

Why `sudo`? As not-privileged user you can't create folders in `/opt`. You need the rights of an administrator, on Linux also known as `root`.

Answer (score 0):

Please run with sudo permission. and check again.